# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/stream/Fusing$ after update to 2.5.2 Akka version

Tags: scala, akka

I am developing a small microservice using Akka. Consists in HttpServer as given below:

```
object HttpServer extends App {

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()

  implicit val system = ActorSystem(config.getString("server.actor-system"))
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  implicit val logger = Logging(system, getClass)

  implicit val employeeRouterActor = system.actorOf(Props[EmployeeRouterActor], name = "employeeRouterActor")

  val employeeRoutes = new EmployeeRoutes()
  val routes = employeeRoutes.route // ~ otherRoutes.route

  val host = config.getString("server.host")
  val port = config.getInt("server.port")
  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(routes, host, port)

  logger.info(s"Server online at http://$host:$port/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
  logger.info(s"Server stopped :(")
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done

}
```

After update to latest Akka version, from _2.12:2.4.17 to _2.12:2.5.2 I always get following error in server start up:

```
objc[27272]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10983c4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10a8914e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
22:29:35.457 [my-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/stream/Fusing$
    at akka.http.scaladsl.HttpExt.fuseServerFlow(Http.scala:87)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.HttpExt.bindAndHandle(Http.scala:181)
    at server.HttpServer$.delayedEndpoint$server$HttpServer$1(HttpServer.scala:36)
    at server.HttpServer$delayedInit$body.apply(HttpServer.scala:17)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at server.HttpServer$.main(HttpServer.scala:17)
    at server.HttpServer.main(HttpServer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.stream.Fusing$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

Server works fine in 2.4.17. Anybody is getting this error after update to 2.5.2?

Comment: Reading official documentation, Akka show latest version with Scala 2.11 version. I am using Scala 2.12. Downgrading to 2.11 I get this error as well.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with akka-http. Have you upgraded that as well?

Comment: This is the issue. I update only Akka but I forgot to update Akka Http from 10.0.4 to 10.0.7. Thanks.

Comment: anyone know the scala 2.11 answer for this? The latest akka http does not support 2.11. I have the issue with using akka http 10.1.14 (the latest support for 2.11) with akka 2.5.16

Answer (score 2):

The solution is update Akka Http as well, to latest version, in this case to 10.0.7.